# ImportError: cannot import name iocpsupport

Tags: python, twisted

I am using twisted API and getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\ggne0622\Desktop\Python\google-python-exercises\babynames\SimpleAgent.py", line 16, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.iocpreactor import reactor
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.iocpreactor.reactor import install
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\reactor.py", line 17, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.iocpreactor import iocpsupport as _iocp
ImportError: cannot import name iocpsupport
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you installed Twisted without building the IOCP extensions.  Either build them (requires a version of MSVC compatible with your Python installation) or use a binary installer - eg one of the several on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted

Comment: I installed twisted using binary installer. I found pyx, .c, .pxi, .h files in iopcsupport folder. Is there any way to compile it?

Comment: What version of Twisted did you install?  Did you use one of the Wheels or did you use the MSI?

Comment: I used twisted MSI version 13.0 the file name is **Twisted-13.0.0.win32-py2.7.msi**

Comment: Can you verify that you're using 32 bit Python as well?  Perhaps you have a 64 bit Python that's using a different install of Twisted than the one created by the MSI?

Comment: yes I am using 32 bit python and my OS is bit XP.please see installation logs below  `*** Installation started 2013/04/18 10:40 ***`  
`Source: C:\Documents and Settings\ggne0622\My`   `Documents\Downloads\pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe`  
`999 Root Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`  
`020 Reg DB Key:`   `[Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall]pywin32-py2.7`  
`040 Reg DB Value:`   `[Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\pywin32-`

Comment: pywin32 is another third-party library for Python.  Unfortunately the "32" is part of the name of the library and doesn't actually indicate whether you have a 32 bit or 64 bit version of Python.  The easiest way I know to check is to run Python and then "import sys; print sys.maxint, sys.maxsize"

Comment: Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Mar 31 2013, 23:48:55) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; print sys.maxint, sys.maxsize
2147483647 2147483647
>>>

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to think some more now.